# Special Maintenance Plan Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, qt, qt4, maintenance-plan

The Maintenance Plan creation is easy. Every body simply use the Maintenance Plan Wizard.
But in this case I want to write program to create a Maintenance Plan using Query. **My plan is Recurrence Full Backup.** I used **Profiler** to detect related queries but the detected queries was **not useful**. What should I do ? **I'm writing my program with Qt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to have a recurring **FULL BACKUP** **job**, it's not necessary to use SSIS packages. you can simply create a job and in its **Steps** section create a new job step and select **(Transact-SQL)** for its type and then write a back up script in that step after that you should set the **Schedules** to make your job recurring. You can have the script of your job by right click on it. now you have a recurring job script without using SSIS programming.

Answer (score 1):

Maintenance Plan generates SSIS Package. Try to open it in BIDS and check used components and code.

If you want to generate SSIS package programmatically there is a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx

Comment: there isn't any c++ code ! specially i'm writing my program with Qt

Comment: You have examples in C#. Maybe there is a posibility of use it with ActiveQT? (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/activeqt-dotnet.html)